# How to open FileZilla Client in windows explorer?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, ftp, windows-explorer

We have a shared drive (windows 7), and I want to set up a server-client FTP system on office local network, so that people can have access to different folders or sub-folders with permission.

I searched a lot, and I found FileZilla. It is a very nice free software, perfect logs, comprehensive permission sets, etc. However, the problem is the user-interface of FileZilla Client, which is not so friendly. For example, when a client wants to open several images and see them, he/she has to open them one by one, compared to windows homegroup, where one can use windows photo viewer and open one image in a folder, and it automatically switches to the next.

Are there any methods so that clients can access the shared files/folders in windows explorer instead of FileZilla client UI?
Any suggestions?

***Edit 1***

I did the following:

In the client PC, in my computer address bar, I typed:

```
ftp://192.168.1.33
```

It asked for username and password, I entered the client user/pass set in filezilla, and it logged in.

I was able to see the files and folders in windows explorer.
This is Awesome.

But the problem is when I double click on files to open them, windows opens them using google chrome.

How can I set it so that every file is opened via its associated standard program? (For example, windows photo viewer opens pictures, adobe reader opens pdf files, etc.)

Any suggestions !?

***Edit 2***

Is **Active Directory** a better choice for me !!!?

Comment: Why are you wanting convert from Windows network file shares to FTP file sharing for a local network?  FTP is typically used for transfer over the internet, and therefore will not display thumbnails of the original photos.

Comment: Thanks @David for your comment. Actually, I needed a shared drive server management program so that different clients can access different folders with permissions. This was not possible by windows homegroup. But the FileZilla can perfectly do this. The only problem is its user-interface.